# BATS - How to force a check for existence of a program to fail?

Tags: bats-core

I have a function that checks for both the existence of a file and if it's executable.

```
is_command() {
  [[ -x "$(command -v "$1" 2> /dev/null)" ]] && return 0
  return 1
}
```

I have a script that is requiring `dos2unix`.

```
is_command 'dos2unix' || { echo 'dos2unix is required'; exit 1}
```

Since `dos2unix` is installed in `/usr/bin` I can't just remove the installed path from `PATH`. I also don't want to (and can't anyway) temporarily rename the actual dos2unix program.

I tried setting an entry in BASH_CMDS, and it works from the command line:

```
$ hash -r ; BASH_CMDS['dos2unix']='/no/such/dir/dos2unix' ; [[ -x "$(command -v dos2unix 2> /dev/null)" ]] ; echo $?
1
```

But this test is not working. The assert_output does not match (it's usage message from later in the program).

```
 @test 'dos2unix does not exist' {
   hash -r
   BASH_CMDS['dos2unix']='/no/such/dir/dos2unix'
   note "dos2unix: $(command -v dos2unix)"
   run ds
   assert_failure
   assert_output 'dos2unix is required'
 }
```

How can I make this work? and why isn't this working?

**Edit:** Make the assert_output match the error generated.

Comment: I'd have to look into it with more detail, but I think this has to do with the scope of BASH_CMDS. My first guess is that if you were to set `BASH_CMDS['dos2unix']='/no/such/dir/dos2unix'` in the same file where `is_command` is, the test wil pass. I'd have to think on this a moment to figure out how to do this the right way, thought.

Comment: I had a little think and added an answer. Don't forget to upvote and accept if my solution works for you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your file-under-test looks like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ds() {

    is_command() {
      [[ -x "$("${command}" -v "$1" 2> /dev/null)" ]] && return 0
      return 1
    }

    is_command 'dos2unix' || { echo 'dos2unix is required'; exit 1; }

    exit 0;
}
```

You would have to somehow "load" this code into your test before it can be run.

Most often, the BATS's `load` function is used for this. However, this (or a similar setup) messes with the scope of `BASH_CMDS`.

This can be resolved by sourcing the file from the global scope:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bats

source "${BATS_TEST_DIRNAME}/ds.sh" # <-- This part is important

@test 'dos2unix does not exist' {
    hash -r

    BASH_CMDS['dos2unix']='/no/such/dir/dos2unix'

    run ds

   assert_failure
   assert_output 'dos2unix is required'
}
```

When I run your original code, it indeed fails. With `source`, the test passes for me.

If this does not resolve your issue, other things might (also) be going on...

Comment: I will look into this, thank you. I have been redirected for the moment, so it will be a little while before I get back to this.

Comment: No worries, let me know whenever you get around to it 